# abort existing requests when using ajaxform

Tags: ajax, ajaxform

I've seen answers for aborting ajax requests, but this question is different as I've inherited a site that uses ajaxform and I need to know how to abort existing requests made using that.

```
 <form id="inventory_search" method='post'>
    <fieldset class="invent-checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="field1" value="field1" id="field1" 1 />
        <label for="field1"><span>field1</span></label>
 </form>

 inventory_options = {
    target:        '#search_result', 
    // other available options:
    url:       'mysite.com/inventory' 
 };


 // bind form using 'ajaxForm'
 $('#inventory_search').ajaxForm(inventory_options);
```

then just call submit when a form field is updated

```
$('#inventory_search').submit();
```

Comment: It depends on how your site is using `AjaxForm`. I recommend using an `array`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but how would you use an array?

Comment: Instead of using "ajaxForm", you could simply use `$.ajax` and save all requests in an array, when you want to cancel, use a loop (`for`, `while`, etc), something like: `for(...) { Arr[i].abort(); }`